# How to get oauth2 client app from Django request

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

I'm using `oauth2_provider` + `rest_framework`. I have configured several client applications, and they successfully authenticate and receive access tokens.

I would like to have the client app in the request (Eg. `request.client`). Perhaps I should create some kind of middleware, which sets it, but I'm not sure what is the proper way to do it. Or maybe this functionality is already provided by the `oauth2_provider`/`oauthlib`, and I have overlooked it?

The client should be set when:

- a valid access token is provided
- valid app credentials are provided (like when requesting access token)

Python v3.5.3, Django v1.10.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oauth2_provider `AccessToken` has a [foreign key](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/0.12.0/oauth2_provider/models.py#L203)
 to the application issued that token

You can get the application form the access token like this: `application = request.auth.application`

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractApplication` class has foreign key to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/0.12.0/oauth2_provider/models.py#L62

So if you are using default `Application` class you could get the clients by `request.user.oauth2_providers_applications`

Comment: This relationship determines the owner of the application, not the application that issued the token used to authenticate the current user. Also it is irrelevant when no user credentials are provided (only client app ones)